# Background services not working while application remove from task manager

Tags: android

**I insert the service class as follow**

this is my code

```
 public class MyTestService extends IntentService {

        public MyTestService() {
            super("MyTestService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            // Do the task here
            Log.i("MyTestService", "Service running");

           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Start background",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            return START_STICKY;


        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return super.onBind(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.i("MyTestService", "Service Destroy");
        }

    }'
```

**Permission in manifest**

This is services register

```
<service
   android:name=".MyTestService"
   android:process=".Broadcast_alram"`enter code here`
   android:exported="false" >
</service>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ill not put any code, but your service is IntentService, meaning it will kill it self after handling Intent. In your case it will execute Log. line and finish it self, also by killing process in which it runs if its separate process than app (in your case it is, it is how you specified it in manifest).

You should extend Service class rather then IntentService, also implement threading for background jobs. And when you have a Service, you have to stop it yourself with stopSelf() or stopService(). https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: It is not working in lenovo vibe(lollipop). When I removed from task manager it not works. Means Service not running at background

Comment: I got the solution for this. Simple put this in activity . android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true" .Application never kill.